# What technique I'm applying to reduce code?

Tags: javascript, oop

What kind of programming technique am I applying when I call an Object inside a Object to extend the object?

On my Job, we have a rule that no JS file may have more 50 lines. So when we have an very large Object we separate the code on new child objects but work as single Object:

```js
function ObjetoA(parent){
   parent.showMessage() = function () {
      console.log('HOLA MUNDO');
   }
}

function Objeto(){

   new ObjectoA(this); //this one

   this.sayHiAgain() = function () {
      console.log('HOLA MUNDO OTRA VEZ');
   } 
}

let Prueba = new Objecto();
Prueba.showMessage();// it works
```

Comment: _"we have a rule that no JS file must have more 50 lines"_ :(

Comment: *we have a rule that no JS file must have more 50 lines.* — that's ridiculous.

Comment: I think by "programming technique" the OP means "Design pattern", but I'm not sure.

Comment: The code you've shown us is not syntactically valid and does not do what you claim that it does!

Comment: Get that rule changed.  Any manager that imposes such a ridiculous constraint should be fired.

Comment: I you remove new here `new ObjectoA(this);` this would look like the simplest form of a mixin. If you do `var inst = new ObjectA()` and then return `inst` from the constuctor that would be "parasitic inheritance".

Comment: The "unclear what you're asking" close votes are somewhat baffling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see what's going on:

- When you call `Objeto()`, the code `new ObjetoAA(this)` is run.
- Now, `ObjetoAA(parent)` is run, which sets the property `showMessage` on `parent`. This property is a function. So now the `Objecto` has a function property `showMessage`.

I don't think there's any particular name for this pattern in the way that you've implemented it. It's just... using objects. I will say that it's an inventive way to extend/modify/split/compose a class. It's sort of simulating a *mixin*.

But it shouldn't be necessary: look at the gymnastics you've had to go through just to meet an arbitrary line count limit. Did it improve your productivity? Did it improve the readability and maintainability of your code? Nope.

Some limit probably makes sense: nobody wants to scan through 30,000 lines of JavaScript in a single file (at least, not the unminified version); but 50 is a very, very small limit. I recommend that you push back on this policy if you can.

Comment: Did it improve your productivity?: It do, some time when we need to reuse code we refer the class Object, without abusing copy and paste.

Comment: @alexgomez88 Permitting code re-use is a completely different thing from splitting up source code files.